# MPI Scatter 2D Allocated Complex Double

Tags: mpi, scatter

Using MPI and C, I'm looking to distribute (scatter and gather) a 2D array of complex double values (ie. every element in the 2D array is of type *complex double*, so has a *creal* and *cimag* component).  If I use regular declaration of a 2D array of size *n*-by-*n*:

```
double complex grid[n][n];
```

Everything works just fine, BUT my program will fail depending on the size of *n*, giving a "segmentation fault" error.  Anything above, say, 256 will immediately spit out a "segmentation fault" error.  This is the problem that I'm having and am failing miserably to figure out.

After browsing through numerous similar issues, I'm guessing my problem is that I'm overloading the stack memory (something I'm honestly not 100% in understanding), meaning that I need to dynamically allocate my 2D arrays using *malloc* or *calloc*.

However, in my understanding, allocating a 2D array that you can call like grid[n][n] won't work since the allocated memory is not necessarily aligned, meaning that MPI_Scatter fails.

```
double complex **alloc_2d_complex(int rows, int cols){
    double complex *data = (complex double*) malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(complex double));
    double complex **array = (complex double**) malloc(rows*sizeof(complex double*));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);

    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
   double complex **grid;
   grid = alloc_2d_complex(n,n);
/* Continue to initialize MPI and attempt Scatter... */
}
```

I've tried initializing a 2D by this method and scatter does fail for me, giving errors "memcpy argument memory ranges overlap" since something in memory apparently doesn't line up right.

This means I must allocate everything in 1D arrays in row-major order, like:

```
grid[y][x] ==> grid[y*n + x]
```

I'm *really, really* trying to avoid this because I'm dealing with numerous transposed and untransposed matrices (which is hard enough to keep track of in [y][x] logic) and it's going to make things difficult to keep track of for my purpose, but fine, if it's what I have to do then let's get it over with.  But this ALSO doesn't work with MPI_Scatter, giving me once again "memcpy" errors, which I am utterly dumbfounded by.  Below is an example of how I'm trying to do everything using 1D arrays.  Since I'm getting the same error for this and the 2D allocated array, maybe the 2D allocation will work and I'm just missing something here.  I'm only using a number of processors, *numProcs*, that can evenly divide *n*.

```
int n = 128;
double complex *grid = malloc(n*n*sizeof(complex double));

/* ... Initialize MPI ... */

stepSize = (int) n/numProcs;
double complex *gridChunk = malloc(stepSize*n*sizeof(complex double));

/* ... Initialize grid[y*n+x] Values... */

MPI_Scatter(&grid, n*stepSize, MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,
                &gridChunk, n*stepSize, MPI_C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX,
                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: The send and receive buffers are `grid` and `gridChunk` (e.g. you need to remove the `&`)

Comment: That did indeed fix the 1D array execution!  I thought the `&` was necessary since `grid` and `gridChunk` are allocated, and so you have to use pointers

Comment: These are both pointers akready, and this is what `MPI_Scatter()` expects. For the 2D array, use `array[O]`

Comment: That worked like a champ for the 2D array too!  Wow, I even had that on a previous version but got rid of it.  Thank you much!  My migraine is officially alleviated.